# Style in one component is over riding style in another component in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm having a X component with a card container. When I click on the card I'm taken to another component which has A,B,C components nested in a container. Component A also has a card container but with different css styling. When I click back and come to X component the card container's css is replaced with A component's CSS.

I'm using Viewencapsulation.none in A component as I have to override some of the material CSS. My requirement is that when I come back to X component the CSS of A should not override it.

This is the CSS in A component

```
    `.card{
     max-width: 270px !important;
     margin: auto;
     transition: all ease 0.3s;
     box-shadow: 0 8px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     background:'#7E7E7E'
     }`
```

This is the CSS in X component

```
    `  .card {
          display:block;
         /* text-align: center !important; */
         perspective: 150rem;
-        moz-perspective: 150rem;
         position: relative;
         height: 30rem;
         /* padding: calc((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 5); */
         padding-left: 3vw;
         padding-right: 3vw;
        }`
```

Since there is max-width in A component my X component also takes up that and is making it look awkward and I can't remove that max-width from A because of my styling.

Decorator in X component

```
   `@Component({
    selector: 'app-X',
    templateUrl: './X.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./X.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
```

Without ViewEncapsulation.None it works as expected, but I need that encapsulation to be none to override this in material

```
        `  .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
          border-color:#fff !important;
         }

        .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
           color:rgb(66, 134, 244) !important;
         background-color:#fff !important
        }`
```

Comment: Write the css for a A component more specifically, For eg - give a class .a-component for A, and you could write .a-component .card { ...... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Css more specifically for A-component. Give a class .a-component to the parent div. Style A-component this way :

If you are using sass

```
.a-component {
     .card{
       max-width: 270px !important;
       margin: auto;
       transition: all ease 0.3s;
       box-shadow: 0 8px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
       background:'#7E7E7E'
     }`
 }
```

If you are using css

```
.a-component .card{
       max-width: 270px !important;
       margin: auto;
       transition: all ease 0.3s;
       box-shadow: 0 8px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
       background:'#7E7E7E';
 }
```